# Storing unused guitar strings

Tags: guitar, strings

I was going to change the strings on my guitar today with older string packs that I haven't completely used and a new pack. Since the low E, A, D, and G rarely break I have an excess supply of them and tried to use them instead of using all the new strings out of a new pack. I noticed that some of my older strings have already started to rust and threw them out immediately instead of putting them on my guitar. Is there a way I can store these excess strings so they can be used at a later date or should I just buy a new pack of strings every time I change my guitar strings?

Comment: Change strings more often, problem solved ;).

Comment: You guitarists are all cheapskates :-).  Take a look at what it costs me for decent 'cello strings!

Comment: Is there anything wrong with those rusted strings, besides appearance? I presume if they play the same as non-rusty ones, there should be no problem?

Comment: @KubaOber - no guitarist that knows what he's doing would use rusty strings !Simple fact - they don't play the same as non-rusty ones.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - you've mentioned this before. Why not take up the guitar instead ?!Seriously, do they need changing as often ? Like 2 to 3 months if you play guitar a lot. (I used to change every other gig).

Comment: @Tim I change the upper strings every 6 months & the lower roughly yearly; a pro might do twice as often.  But I've heard from a lot of guitarists who change strings more like monthly or as you noted, even after a couple strenuous gigs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - yes, they lose their brilliance quite soon. If it's jazz, that seems to be not so bad - most people want a more mellow sound, but for rock etc., the top end drops off considerably quickly. Maybe not so much an issue for cellists, I guess.

Comment: @Tim This gets me to wonder, then, how close are those strings to their tensile strength limit. If rust changes the sound, that would mean that the slightly reduced cross-section at the rust spots is damping the string by plastically deforming (even if very slightly) and dumping energy out of the string. I mean - there must be a physical reason for why it's so. This got me quite curious.

Comment: @KubaOber - not very close, particularly if they're light gauge rather than medium/heavy. It is possible, but not recommended, to tune them an octave higher than intended. Thus they are not even at half of their tensile strength limit. It's the smoothness of feel as much as anything,as well as the lack of tone. I guess their cross-section is no longer uniformly circular, but ignorance stops me going further.

Comment: @Tim OK. So, as far as the behavior of string goes, the cross-section's shape shouldn't matter all that much, unless torsional oscillation of the string becomes an issue. I'd really love to see a spectrum of a recorded new vs. rusted string. I'm still curious :)

Comment: Sorry, can't help. Never have rusty strings !!

Answer (score 7):

I have strings which could be ten years old or  more, not stored particularly well, and they are fine when they get put on, and seem to last as well as new ones. They are mostly Ernie Ball and Picato (others are available !) and stored in a conservatory which probably isn't completely dry. Put yours into a sealed plastic bag, with silica gel, that should solve the problem. A warm room ought to be a good place, too.

Because I use a strange mix of strings, as in I can't buy a set with exactly the right gauges for me, I tend to buy, for example, 10 of 008s, 10 of 010s, etc, so it's an idea for you. It's not necessary to buy a whole pack that may not all be used.Ask for a bit of discount for bulk buying !

EDIT:Change of plan here! Recently opened a sealed set of strings, and the plain ones had rust marks in certain places around the windings, so, like every 8" or so along their length. They'd been stored for several years, but still should have been pristine. Spoke to the manufacturers, who sent me replacement sets for around the half dozen affected ones - gratis! No names - as firstly it's a brickbat against them, but secondly, it's praise for 'doing the right thing'. I actually rubbed the rust off with some fine sandpaper, and they *seem* to be o.k., but wouldn't use them on an electric, although they seem fine on an acoustic. And no, my fingers aren't ripped to shreds. And, none have broken either. Waste not, want not...